# How can I find redundant groups in a pandas dataframe using groupby in Python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, set

Below is the example dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5], 'b':[1001,1002,1232,1001,1002,3002,1021,2021,4000,1002,1002,2031,1200]})
```

```
df
    a   b
0   1   1001
1   1   1002
2   1   1232
3   2   1001
4   2   1002
5   3   3002
6   4   1021
7   4   2021
8   4   4000
9   5   1002
10  5   1002
11  5   2031
12  5   120
```

I grouped the dataframe by column 'a', so that each group contains a set of values; like group 1 contains {1001,1002,1232}, group 2 - {1001,1002}, etc.:

```
df.groupby('a')
```

Going from top to bottom, let's call a group redundant if it does not contain any new value (every value it contains is already included by some earlier groups in this dataframe).
I need to write a code to find how many groups in the dataframe are redundant?

This is what I tried:

```
groups=[set(i[1]['b']) for i in df.groupby('a')]
covered_groups=[groups[0]]

counter=0
for i in groups[1:]:
    for k in covered_groups:
        if i.issubset(k):
            counter+=1
            break
    covered_groups.append(i)
        
print(counter)
```

Output is 4, instead of 1. Not sure whats' wrong here.
Also maybe preferably there're pandas built in methods to achieve same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure it out a pure pandas solution, but you can try something like this:

```
values = set()                     
count = 0
                              
for group in df.groupby('a')['b']: 
    are_in = group[1].isin(values) 
                                                   
    if are_in.all():               
       count += 1
             
    values = values.union(group[1])

print(count) #1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
# aggregate as set and sort by decreasing size
tmp = (df.groupby('a')['b'].agg(set)
         .sort_values(key=lambda s: s.str.len(), ascending=False)
      )

# compare set to larger ones
keep = []
drop = []
for s in tmp:
    if any(s.issubset(s2) for s2 in keep):
        drop.append(s)
        continue
    else:
        keep.append(s)

keep
# [{1001, 1002, 1232}, {1021, 2021, 4000}, {1002, 1200, 2031}, {3002}]

drop
# [{1001, 1002}]
```

Comment: Groups must not be sorted. The original direction must be retained and every new group should be checked if it's a subset of a any of the previous group. I guess your code works only if groups are sorted, right?